# How to do Authentication in Metro App with custom STS

Tags: wif, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can anyone share the guide to do authentication in Metro App with custom STS server. I searched all over the internet but didn't find any solution for this.

Regards,
Bhavik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article [Using ACS in Metro Style Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2011/09/14/using-acs-in-metro-style-applications.aspx) may be of use.

The general principles will be the same.